# Conversion factor for bond with coupon=yield

Tags: bond

Please illustrate that a bond with maturity N years that has coupon equal to its yield is associated with the conversion factor of 1.

I do this by writing out
$$\frac1{100} \left( \sum_{t=1}^N \left[ \frac{100 (0.06)}{1.06^t} \right]+\frac{100}{1.06^N} \right)$$
but I do not get that this = 1.

I use the formula:

$$\sum_{k=m}^n a^k = 
\begin{cases}\frac{a^{n+1} - a^m}{a-1}, \quad &a \neq 1\\n-m+1, \quad &a=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: I solved it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given a bond with Coupon = Yield = $6 \%$ and Maturity $N$. We want to check that the conversion factor = 1, in other words that
        $$\frac1{100} 
  \left(
  \frac{100}{1.06^N}     +     
  \sum_{t=1}^N \frac{100 \cdot 0.06}{1.06^t}
  \right) 
  = 1 
  $$
        or equivalently 
        $$
    \frac{1}{1.06^N}     +     
  \sum_{t=1}^N \frac{0.06}{1.06^t}
  = 1.
  $$

The first term is 
$\frac{1}{1.06^N} = 
\left( 
 \frac{1}{1.06} 
\right)^N.$
The second term can be simplified using the formula for geometric sums
$$\sum_{t=1}^N 
\frac{0.06}{1.06^t} = 
1  -   \left( 
   \frac{1}{1.06} 
       \right)^N.$$
Now we add the first term and the second term and see that
$$\left( 
  \frac{1}{1.06} 
      \right)^N 
\quad + \quad
1  -   \left( 
   \frac{1}{1.06} 
       \right)^N
=
1.
$$

Comment: Well done! Also note that in practice, conversion factor for a 6% coupon bond maybe not be exactly 1.0 (could be 0.9999) due to the rounding of the maturity date and the rounding convention of the conversion factor.